# How to add an HTML attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, I have this jQuery image slideshow that uses the attribute "control" inside an <a>. Seeing how it didn't validate I searched for a way to add this attribute inside my HMTL via jQuery but I didn't really find anything relevant. Now I don't really care about how valid my page is, but I'm really curious in how to add an HTML attribute inside an HTML tag.

In case I wasn't clear enough with my explanation, I have this code:

```
<a id="previous" control="-6" href="#"></a>
```

And I want to add **control="-6"** with jQuery.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the jQuery version has been *well* covered here, I thought I'd offer *something different*, so here a native DOM API alternative:

```
document.getElementById('previous').setAttribute('control','-6');
```

Yes, I know you asked for jQuery. Never hurts to know the native way too. :o)

Answer (score 27):

Use jQuery's [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function

```
$("#previous").attr("control", "-6");
```

An example

```
// Try to retrieve the control attribute
// returns undefined because the attribute doesn't exists
$("#previous").attr("control");

// Set the control attribute
$("#previous").attr("control", "-6");

// Retrieve the control attribute (-6)
$("#previous").attr("control");
```

See this [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRTJc/)

---

You can alternatively use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function to store values on elements. Works the same way, for example:

```
$("#previous").data("control"); // undefined
$("#previous").data("control", "-6"); // set the element data
$("#previous").data("control"); // retrieve -6
```

Using `data` you can store more complex values like objects

```
$("#previos").data("control", { value: -6 });
($("#previos").data("control")).value; // -6
```

See a [data example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGf7Z/)

Comment: The right answer. However, I am against using data(), I don't think html nodes are the proper place to store data, that's mixing V and M. I always create a model object that is used to maintain any common data on the screen. However, it's useful for small apps and light page enhancements

Answer (score 2):

Let me see if I understood you.
You have, for example, the code:

```
<a id="previous" href="#"></a>
```

And by jQuery you want it to be:

```
<a id="previous" control="-6" href="#"></a>
```

Is it right?
If it is. You just have to do:

```
$('#previous').attr('control', -6);
```

If an attribute doesn't exists it's created by jQuery.
So, to remove it you can do:

```
$('#previous').removeAttr('control');
```

What you're doing doesn't respect the html rules and everything else, but it works fine, a lot of plugins do the same. ;D

I hope this could be helpful!

See you!

Comment: can you give an example of a rule not being respected?

Comment: HTML rules to the letter doesn't accept custom tag attributes.
Try using the W3C Validator http://validator.w3.org/.

Nothing to worry about, they just work fine. The problem is that your custom attributes may conflict with plugins' custom ones, or even with some new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#previous').attr('control', '-6');
```

Why? the [$.attr();](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function of jQuery allows you to add, get or update attributes (class, id, href, link, src, control and everything else!).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#previous").attr("control", "-6");
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<a id="previous" href="#">...</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#previous').attr('control', '-6');
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) will do that.  Example:

```
$("#previous").attr("control", "-6");
```

Also check out this example at http://jsfiddle.net/grfSN/.