# Adding attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tags

How can I add an attribute into specific HTML tags in jQuery?

For example, like this simple HTML:

```
<input id="someid" />
```

Then adding an attribute disabled="true" like this:

```
<input id="someid" disabled="true" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add an HTML attribute with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866063/how-to-add-an-html-attribute-with-jquery)

Answer (score 632, accepted):

You can add attributes using `attr` like so:

```
$('#someid').attr('name', 'value');
```

However, for DOM properties like `checked`, `disabled` and `readonly`, the proper way to do this (as of JQuery 1.6) is to use `prop`.

```
$('#someid').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: For me `$('#someid').prop('disabled', true);` doesn't work, but `$('#someid').attr('disabled', true);` works fine.

Comment: Agree with @VukašinManojlović.. for me the same.

Comment: Before you decide whether you're going to use `attr` or `prop`, it's important to understand the difference between properties and attributes. Without understanding the difference, you're likely to run into unexpected behavior. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028/3367343

Comment: can prop be used as a replacement for attr now? or it is used in some special cases only?

Answer (score 56):

**best solution:** from jQuery v1.6 you can use  [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) to add a property

```
$('#someid').prop('disabled', true);
```

to remove it, use  `removeProp()`

```
$('#someid').removeProp('disabled');
```

[`Reference`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp)

> Also note that the .removeProp()
>   method should not be used to set these
>   properties to false. Once a native
>   property is removed, it cannot be
>   added again. See .removeProp() for
>   more information.

Answer (score 39):

You can do this with jQuery's [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) function, which will set attributes. Removing them is done via the [`.removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr) function.

```
//.attr()
$("element").attr("id", "newId");
$("element").attr("disabled", true);

//.removeAttr()
$("element").removeAttr("id");
$("element").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Bonus for including the remove function!

Comment: IT DOESNT WORK!

Answer (score 17):

```
$('#someid').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#someid').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

Answer (score 4):

Add attribute as:

```
$('#Selector_id').attr('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.some_selector').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
<script> 
   $('#someid').attr('disabled', 'true'); 
</script>
```

Comment: it would be nicer if you could have some explanation

Comment: Just include jQuery link after write code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
`  Text inside $ symbol select all element with id = someid , disabled attribute of this id change to true

Answer (score 0):

This could be more helpfull....

```
$("element").prop("id", "modifiedId");
//for boolean
$("element").prop("disabled", true);
//also you can remove attribute
$('#someid').removeProp('disabled');
```

Comment: Attributes and properties aren't exactly the same. For example, "id" is an attribute, not a property. You use `.attr()` to set or read it. See the paragraph "Attributes vs. Properties" under [.prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) in the jQuery docs. Also see [Paul Rosania's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5995650/3345375) above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourid').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use removeProp() for "checked", "disabled" or "selected", it might not work. To remove property use prop with 'false' parameter.

```
        $('.my-input').prop('disabled', true); //adding property
        $('.my-input').prop('disabled', false); //removing property
```

documentation: https://api.jquery.com/removeprop/