# Overriding JSF Primefaces Message Tag

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Can I override the default implementation of `<p:message ../>` to always implicitly have `display="text"` instead of typing out in full in time?

```
<p:message for="hotelName" display="text" />
```

Comment: Just an idea, instead of overriding which might(and maybe not) cause you troubles if the original <p:message will be modified you can add this display using jQuery like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5995650/617373 , just use selector for the messages tag, (you can add this to all elements with class "ui-messages ui-widget"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extend the PrimeFaces' `MessageRenderer` for that. Just override the `encodeEnd()` method wherein you set the default attribute before calling the super method.

Here's a self-containing kickoff example:

```java
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.component.message.MessageRenderer;

public class CustomMessageRenderer extends MessageRenderer {

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        component.getAttributes().put("display", "text"); // You might want to check first if it isn't already set.
        super.encodeEnd(facesContext, component);
    }

}
```

which you need to register in `faces-config.xml` as follows (no, annotation magic won't work in overriding the existing renderers which are by itself registered by XML, so the XML is absolutely necessary):

```xml
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.MessageRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.CustomMessageRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

But easier would be to just throw in a little bit of CSS to hide the icon.

```
.ui-message-error-icon {
    display: none;
}
```

Creating a composite component as suggested by the other answer isn't exactly trivial because the `for` target of the `<p:message>` isn't contained within the same composite.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a Facelet Composition Component for that.