# Add the Class Dynamically using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How can i add the class selectors dynamically to the `img` tag. For Example:
img tag should be inside the anchor tag then only the class name:sample should add dynamically whichever anchor tag contain img like,
**Before:**

```
<a href="image.png"><img src="image.png"/></a>
```

**After:**

```
<a href="image.png"><img src="image.png" class="sample"/></a>
```

If already image tag contain class then remove that class and the new class is possible in jquery. I am not sure, how can i do this in jQuery. 
Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks,
vicky

Comment: Just use: [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) and [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/). Or use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) instead of `.hasClass()`.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995628/adding-attribute-in-jquery to remove attribute add removeAttr() before the attr()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to toggle your class. To do this, see:

```
$("img").toggleClass("border");
```

I made an example for you on CodePen. [Just click here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cdkae).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('your selector').addClass('sample'); //It can be select,img,a,etc.. });
```

Be specific in your tag for choosing. I use in CakePHP 3.x Date HtmlHelper field and it worked like a magic.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('a[href=image.png] > img').hasClass('sample')){
    $('a[href=image.png] > img').removeClass('sample');
}
```

And `addClass` for `else` part.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily via jQuery.addClass and jQuery.removeClass APIs..

Add Class - http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
Remove Class - http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('a img').removeClass().addClass('example')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a >img').addClass('sample'); //direct descendant of a
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML code:

```
<img id="testImg" src="xyz.jpg" />
```

css code:

`.displayNone{
  display:none;
}`

jquery - to add class

```
`$("#testImg").addClass("displayNone");`
```

jquery - to remove class

`$("#testImg").removeClass("displayNone");`