# Dynamically added property not visible in html element

Tags: jquery, html, attr, prop

I added the 'disabled' property to a `textbox` input field dynamically with `jQuery`. But looking to the generated `HTML`, it's not visible on the `textbox` input field to which I have added the 'disabled' property to.

And because it's not added to it, my other jQuery function never gets entered.

Here is my code:

This happens some where in the doc load event:

`$('.testGroup :input').prop('disabled', true)`

This function shows a tooltip when you `click` or `hover` over disabled inputs:

```
$('input:disabled').after(function (e) {
        debugger;
        d = $("<div>");
        i = $(this);
        d.css({
            height: i.outerHeight(),
            width: i.outerWidth(),
            position: "absolute",
        })
        d.css(i.offset());
        d.attr("title", i.attr("title"));
        d.tooltip();
        return d;
    });
```

I have used/tried both `prop()` and `attr()`, but non of them enters my `after()` function.

According to [Paul Rosania](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5995650/405046) I should use `prop()`.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WB6bM/56/)

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure, see my question updated. Couldn't get the dynamically disable input to work on jsFiddle `('#test').prop('disabled', true);`.

Comment: change ('#test').prop('disabled', true); to $('#test').prop('disabled', true);

Comment: Ah yea of course, stupid me. Fixed and updated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code that adds the tooltip only runs once after the DOM is ready.
You need to call it for every element that you disable.

A simple solution would be to write a method for your tooltip:

```
function AddToolTip() {
    d = $("<div>");
    i = $(this);
    d.css({
        height: i.outerHeight(),
        width: i.outerWidth(),
        position: "absolute",
    })
    d.css(i.offset());
    d.attr("title", i.attr("title"));
    d.tooltip();
    return d;
}
```

Then, use this method to apply the tooltip to the elements that are disabled on DOM ready

`$('input:disabled, button:disabled').after(AddToolTip);`

On disabling an input element, call the method again

`$('#test').prop('disabled', true).after(AddToolTip);`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WB6bM/55/)