# Adding Attributes to HTML elements via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress and there is no way to add custom attribute to HTML element via theme. I found that it can be done via Jquery, but it doesn't help me.

Attributes that I want to add to HTML element on load (No need to click anything specific):

```
data-tf-popup="Vxs1VOeK" 
data-tf-hide-headers="" 
data-tf-transitive-search-params="utm_source, utm_medium,utm_campaign,utm_term,utm_content" 
data-tf-iframe-props="title=Dermatologo konsultacija internetu - iDerma" 
data-tf-medium="snippet" 
data-tf-hidden="utm_source=xxxxx,utm_medium=xxxxx,utm_campaign=xxxxx,utm_term=xxxxx,utm_content=xxxxx"
```

Specific button/item to which I want to add it. Currently it has Ahref, but I will remove the ahref, to keep it empty.

```
<li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-singup menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-37" data-tf-popup="Vxs1VOeK"><a href="https://form.typeform.com/to/Vxs1VOeK">Pradėti konsultaciją</a></li>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: so [select the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and add the attributes....

Comment: "*...[But] it doesn't help me.*" - what are you having problems with? Where are you stuck?

Comment: `$("#menu-item-37").attr("data-tf-popup", "Vxs1VOeK")` etc.   However, it's unclear why this doesn't help you / what it doesn't solve or what those `data-tf-...` attributes are actually used for.   jQuery will not re-read `data-` attributes if it's already read them so you may need to do `$("#menu-item-37").data("tf-popup", "Vxs1VOeK")` but, equally, if you have a third-party plugin (especially as "wordpress") that's already read *and used* those attributes, then you setting them may be too late.

Comment: Also, while this question is on-topic for Stack Overflow; there's a chance it may be a better fit over on [wordpress.se].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding attribute in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995628/adding-attribute-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the attributes via jQuery's [`.attr()` function](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). The first parameter determines the attribute you're adding while the second parameter is the value of the said attribute.

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#element_id').attr('data-tf-popup', 'Vxs1VOeK');
  $('#element_id').attr('data-tf-hide-header', '');
  // ...
});
```

You can make it cleaner by using JSON objects as such:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const attr = {
    'data-tf-popup': 'Vxs1VOeK',
    'data-tf-hide-header': '',
    'data-tf-transitive-search-params': 'utm_source, utm_medium,utm_campaign,utm_term,utm_content',
    // ...
  }
  
  for (let key in attr) {
    $('#element_id').attr(key, attr[key]);
  }
});
```