# jQuery: Shows an error while adding name attribute to elements - setAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table where a button on click adds a new row. I want to add a name attribute each time new row created.

Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
  const $tb = $('#service-table tbody');
  $("tr",$tb).eq(0).hide();
  $("#serviceAdd").on("click",function() {
    const $row = $tb.find("tr").eq(0).clone();
    $row.show();
    $row.find("select").val("").attr("name", "service_id[]"); // reset the select
    $row.find(".s_qty").val().attr("name", "s_qty[]"); // reset the numbers
    $row.find(".s_total").val().attr("name", "s_total[]"); // reset the numbers     
    $tb.append($row);

  });
});
```

It shows error `Uncaught TypeError: $row.find(...).val(...).attr is not a function`

I have tried with many changes but it shows the same error.

How can I add attribute to new rows?

Comment: `).val().` *gets* the value, so it will likely be a string, which doesn't have a `setAttribute` method.  Having said that, `.setAttribute()` is also not a jquery function, so it's probably the line before that one.  Use `$(..).val("").attr("name", "...")`

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Setting attribute in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995628/adding-attribute-in-jquery/5995650#5995650)

Comment: Same thing. I have updated the question with attr(). 

Can you please tell me for my case, which way I can add attribute?

Comment: Debug the value of `$row.find(".s_qty").val()`

Comment: Example here for changing an attribute: https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value

Comment: Solved it. I call each line again without val().

Comment: If you want to reset the value, use `.val('')` like you did in the `select` line.