# jQuery cloned elements with different names

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a problem with my cloned element. My code looks like this:

```
var clone = $('#clone').clone()
$('.addprop').live('click', function() {
    $(clone).clone().addClass('add-margin').removeAttr('id').insertAfter(".addprop");
})
```

It works fine, it doesn't add the id, but now I need to add different name for every cloned element. Can anyone help?

Comment: And what exactly do you have problem with? Don't you know [how to add an attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866063/how-to-add-an-html-attribute-with-jquery)?

Comment: looks like you are removing the id not adding it

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the id because I don't want to duplicate it in cloned element. That is already done, but now I want to add different name="" for every cloned element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var clone = $('#clone').clone();
var increment=0;
$('.addprop').live('click', function() {
    $(clone).clone().addClass('add-margin').attr("name","some-name"+increment).removeAttr('id').insertAfter(".addprop");
    increment++;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P3zMu/1)**

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, it gives "Uncaught ReferenceError: increment is not defined" in java console.