# How to add an alt attribute of img tags with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've put a google map in a page and it makes lots of img tags without the alt attribute, how can I add the alt for each img in a div in jquery, what's I gotta make instead of :

```
$('#map_canvas > img[alt]').attr('image');
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you intend to determine what alt text is appropriate? (`<img src="foo" alt="image">` is almost always horribly wrong and much worse than no alt attribute at all).

Comment: I tried all of your codes and they don't work, are you sure i ain't missing a including script ? i've that :

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add an HTML attribute with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866063/how-to-add-an-html-attribute-with-jquery) -- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: Why do you want an alt tag in the first place? Google maps are hardly to make accessible. And for your SEO tasks it is not necessary, because google maps image will load only with javascript

Comment: you mean SEO won't see the 82 missing alt of images, because if it see that my ranking will be very bad ?

Comment: Crawlers don't parse Javascript, therefore if your intent is to add alt tags to img tags that don't already have them with Javascript for the sole purpose of SEO then you're wasting your time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To set alternative text to all the images:

```
$('#map_canvas > img').attr('alt', 'Alternative text');
```

To set alternative text to images that does not have `alt` attribute:

```
$('#map_canvas > img:not([alt])').attr('alt', 'Alternative text');
```

Comment: weird, maybe i'm missing a including script, are there another inclusions apart these:<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
$("#map_canvas > img:not([alt])").attr("alt", "<YOURALTTEXT>");
```

Comment: +1 for not overwriting image which already have `alt` attributes.

Answer (score 4):

This work:

```
$('#map_canvas').find('img:not([alt])').attr('alt', 'Alt text');
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
$('#map_canvas > img[alt=""]').each(function()
{
    $(this).attr('alt', $(this).attr('src');
});
```

This would find all images within `#map_canvas` that do not have an `alt` tag, and then set the `alt` tag to be the same as the image `src`.

Alternatively, I would recommend:

```
$('#map_canvas > img[alt=""]').attr('alt', 'Alt text');
```

As this will only add alt tags to images that don't have one.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#map_canvas > img').attr('alt', 'alt_text');
```